# Fetching data with useSWR. Next Image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am fetching data from backend - url without host. In Next Image I pass src with host.But requested url of image is pathname of page + url without host. How is that?

```
const {
    data: page,
    isLoading: loading,
    error,
  } = useSWR(
    `chapter`,

    () => fetcher(`chapter/${currentChapter?._id}`, { currentPage: 1 })
  );
```

NextImage

```
 <NextImage
              src={`http://localhost:3000/${page}`}
              alt="page"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the page data returned from the backend represents the relative path of the image you want to display, including the file extension (e.g., 'path/to/image.jpg')
Instead of concatenating the page data directly with the host, you can let NextImage component to resolve the image path correctly.

```
src={`/${page}`} // Prepend a forward slash (/) to the image path
```